# How big is too big for a DistributedCache file hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

Are there any guidelines for whether to distribute a file using a distributed cache or not ?

I have a file of size 86746785 (I use `hadoop dfs -dus` -  don't know if this is in `bytes` or what). Is it a good idea to distribue this file ?

Comment: hadoop dfs -dus is in bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only viable answer is "it depends".

What you have to consider about using distributed cache is the file gets copied to **every** node that is involved in your task, which obviously takes bandwidth. Also, usually if you want the file in distributed cache, you'll keep the file in memory, so you'd have to take that into consideration.

As for your case -- yes, those are bytes. The size is roughly 86 MB, which is perfectly fine for distributed cache. Anything within a couple hundred MBs should probably still be.

Comment: i would add that it only gets copied to nodes that will actually perform a task for your job - i.e of you job is a single map task, it will only be copied to the node that executes that task, rather then **every** node as you note.

Comment: @ChrisWhite You're right & I somehow didn't think to make that distinction. Edited & added into answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to TC1's answer, also consider:

- When/where are you going to use the file(s) and how big is your cluster?

  - In a many mappers, single reducer (or small number of) scenario where you only need the file in the reducer i would advise against it as you might as well just pull down the file yourself in the reducer (setup method), rather than unnecessarily for each task node your mappers run on - especially if the file is large (this depends on how many nodes you have in your cluster)
- How many files are you putting into the cache?

  - If for some reason you have 100's of files to distribute, you're better off tar'ing them up and putting the tar file in the distributed cache's archives set (the dist cache will take care of untaring the file for you). The thing you're trying to avoid here is if you didn't put them in the dist cache but directly loaded them from HDFS, you may run into a scenario where you have 1000's of mappers and or reducers trying to open the same file which could caused *too many open files* problems for the name node and data nodes

Answer (score 0):

The size of Distributed Cache is 10GB by default. But its better to keep a few MBs of data in Distributed Cache.Otherwise it will affect the performance of your application.